# Visited links in our meta are almost invisible

Tags: feature-request, design, css

Quick, spot the link in this paragraph:

[image]

I understand that meta is supposed to be muted, but I think the brown for visited links is at least a shade too dark. Surely now that I've told you there's a link there, it's easy to spot; but it would not be so obvious if you weren't given a hint in advance.

This is a CSS change request, not a feature request. But I don't think it's a bug per se, since the color was likely chosen intentionally. Instead of #6c5f16 I propose #8e7f38.

Comment: "blogged here about ways to ask more effective questions" right? I see your point, and raise you one upvote for good idea.

Comment: @jcolebrand correct - it's visible if you know you're looking for a link, but if you're scanning the text it does not pop out at all.

Comment: I remember asking quite similar question a couple of years back on UNIX.SE: ["Favourite tagged questions: highlight colors, too bright?.."](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426/favourite-tagged-questions-highlight-colors-too-bright)

Comment: Pinging @Jin - I have bacon

Comment: @Abby any chance of getting some movement here? Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron I was hoping nagging  Jin and adding [tag:design] would land this on his todo.txt but no luck yet. I will ping again.

Comment: @Abby thank you!